# How to draw circle around round image with small circle on outer circle border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating testimonial slider using html CSS and jquery like this one
[image]

I tried using html css bellow is code and screenshot

HTML code :-

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/testo.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="testo-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 client">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <h3>Complex Roy</h3>
    <h5>Web Designer</h5>
    <h6>Logictrix technologies is a good company. it's give batter products and services.Logictrix technologies is a good comp. it's give batter products and services.Logictrix technologies is a good company. it's give batter products and services. Logictrix technologies is a good company. it's give batter products and services.</h6>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
   <div class="big-cir">
    <center><img class="img-responsive img-circle" id="profile-image" height="250" width="250" src="image/client-1.png"></center> 
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :-

```
.testo-body{
background-color:white;
}
.out-cir{
 margin-top:-23%;
}
.profile{
margin-top:-20.5%;
margin-left:-31%;
}
.client{
background-color:#161e43;
color:white;
margin-top:20%;
}
.blue1{

}
.big-cir{
 background-color:none;
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:relative;
 border-color:rgb(167,183,254);
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:2px;
 margin-top:-23%;



}

.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
 margin-top:7%;

}
```

Screenshot Using HTML :-
[image]

Now how I can put circle on outer circle line and make them animate ?
any suggestion or code will help me a lot

Comment: You can do it with both Css and Jquery.
Use css animation property to animate the 3 dots over the outer-border and 
jquery to tilde the animation for specific time.

Comment: @Deepakswain but first how to set dot circle on big outer circle ?

Comment: you have to use an image for this.

Comment: @Deepakswain can please show me code how I can do ?

Comment: Ofcourse you dont have to use an image, you make a <div> and make it 10px high and wide and set border-radius to be 5px, you know have a circle.

Comment: Problem is not creating small circle but to put that circle on another circle border

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create small circle on outer big circle using `before` and `after` property in css. I have tried this. I am able to create two circle's. hope this helps you to get right way... (I will update if I able to create third one or multiple)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="testo-body">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 client">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <h3>Complex Roy</h3>
               <h5>Web Designer</h5>
               <h6>Logictrix technologies is a good company. it's give batter products and services.Logictrix technologies is a good comp. it's give batter products and services.Logictrix technologies is a good company. it's give batter products and services. Logictrix technologies is a good company. it's give batter products and services.</h6>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 client-image">
            <center><img class="img-responsive img-circle" id="profile-image" height="250" width="250" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></center>
            <div class="big-cir">
               <div class="small-cir"></div>
               <div class="small-cir2"></div>
               <div class="small-cir3"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.testo-body {
   background-color: white;
}

.out-cir {
   margin-top: -23%;
}

.profile {
   margin-top: -20.5%;
   margin-left: -31%;
}

.client {
   background-color: #161e43;
   color: white;
   margin-top: 10%;
}

.blue1 {}

.big-cir {
   height: 300px;
   width: 300px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;
   border-color: rgb(167, 183, 254);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   animation: dotmove cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1) 2s infinite;
}

.big-cir > .small-cir {
   background-color: #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   border-color: rgb(167, 183, 254);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 5px;
   content: "";
   left: 90px; // you may need to change this
}

.big-cir > .small-cir2 {
   background-color: #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   border-color: rgb(167, 183, 254);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 5px;
   content: "";
   left: 290px;
   top: 130px;
}

.big-cir > .small-cir3 {
   background-color: #000;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   border-color: rgb(167, 183, 254);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 2px;
   padding: 5px;
   content: "";
   left: 150px;
   top: 290px;
}

.img-circle {
   margin: 25px;
   position: absolute;
}

.client-image {
   margin-top: -230px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

@keyframes dotmove {
   from {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
   }
   to {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rahul8590/k0y00Lqc/10/

Comment: Yes it's working if you can animate it too I'll accept it as an answer, thanks again

Comment: I updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/brwg5kg8/ now i can create multiple circle using div

Comment: Nice...I am making animation it rotating the dot's but along with image inside...if you don't mind can we make it different rather than child..

Comment: Yes all I is want dynamic dots so we can add multiple and animate it over circle

Comment: I have updated the code, animation working, you may change that animation speed, effect as you need...hope this helps you. :)